# JSON array objects not being read correctly from jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I'm a bit stuck, but this has to be user error; the following works, in a sense. It's adding new options to the select but there's a new option for every character in the JSON response, e.g.

Select form

{

[

"

N

a

m

e

"

:

and so on.

Firebug Lite logs the JSON response as:

```
{"d":"[{\"Name\":\"Monday\"},{\"Name\":\"Tuesday\"},{\"Name\":\"Wednesday\"}]"}
```

Here is the page source:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: '/MyWebService/MyWebService.asmx/GetDays',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: '{"_category":"Administration"}',
            success: function (response) {
                // Clear the list and add an instructional item...
                $("#FormsSelect").get(0).options.length = 0;
                $("#FormsSelect").get(0).options[0] = new Option("Select form", "-1");
                // Add each element returned from the server...
                $.each(response.d, function (index, category) {
                    $('#FormsSelect').append(
                    $('<option></option>').val(index).html(category)
                    );
                });
            },
            error: function (request, error) {
                alert("An error occurred: " + request.status + "\n" + request.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thoughts on why this is occurring?

Thanks,
Aaron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice how the response

```
"[{\"Name\":\"Monday\"},{\"Name\":\"Tuesday\"},{\"Name\":\"Wednesday\"}]"
```

is a string. If you loop through a string, you get it character by character.

If you want to parse the string as an array, you should do something like this, using the [jQuery `parseJSON` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/):

```
var arr = $.parseJSON(response.d);
$.each(arr, function(index, category) { 
 // ...
```

Also note that you probably want to do

```
.html(category.Name);
```

instead of

```
.html(category);
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, that's done the trick. If I had enough rep I'd mark this as the answer.

Comment: @Aaron Just press the green checkmark next to the answer if you don't have enough rep to upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$('<option></option>').val(index).html(category.Name)
```